# Objective-C wrapper class for CGContext?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Has anyone created a wrapper class for the CGContext group of functions?

I created a simple Gradient class yesterday which encapsulates a subset of CGGradient functionality for simpler memory management.  It was pretty straightforward.  But there are obviously quite a few more CGContext operations, and I'm not sure I'd want to reinvent the wheel there.

Essentially what I'm looking for is stuff like...

```
@interface CGContext : NSObject
{
    CGContextRef context;
}

+ (CGContext *) bitmapContextWithData:(void *)data
                                width:(size_t)width
                               height:(size_t)height
                     bitsPerComponent:(size_t)bitsPerComponent
                          bytesPerRow:(size_t)bytesPerRow
                           colorspace:(CGColorSpaceRef)colorspace
                           bitmapInfo:(CGBitmapInfo)bitmapInfo;

- (void) saveGState;
- (void) restoreGState;

- (void) setBlendMode:(CGBlendMode)mode;

- (void) addLineToPoint:(CGPoint)point;
- (void) addLineToPointX:(CGFloat)x pointY:(CGFloat)y;

- (void) drawImage:(CGImageRef)image rect:(CGRect)rect;

- (void) concatCTM:(CGAffineTransform)transform;
- (CGAffineTransform) getCTM;

@end
```

and so forth.

(I do 99% of my drawing into off-screen bitmaps, which is why I care about memory management in this case.  If I was always drawing into the current UI graphics context such as the active screen, then I wouldn't really find a wrapper class to be of much use.)

Comment: Are you on the Mac or iOS? The Mac has NSGradient, NSBitmapImageRep, NSAffineTransform, and NSGraphicsContext.

Comment: Why bother? Usually thin wrapper classes like this are a waste of time. They're a lot of boring code that doesn't do any real work, but just shuffles arguments around. A higher level of abstraction might be more useful.

Comment: @KurtRevis: The `bitmapContextWithData:::::::` method would make the creation of a bitmap context more readable—long lists of arguments such as that are where Objective-C's names-and-values syntax shines. Aside from that, yes, I agree—higher-level wrappers such as AppKit's (or just using AppKit's, if this is for the Mac) are greatly preferable.

Comment: @KurtRevis — Yup, just boring code that shuffles arguments around. But makes memory management so much cleaner. I love ARC, but I don't like that I still have to call CGFooRetain(), CGFooRelease(), and CFBridgingRetain(), CFBridgingRelease() a fair amount. I just don't want to have to think about those at all.

Comment: I agree that that sort of thing is useful. However, I don't think it necessarily means that you need to write a wrapper for _every_ CG function.

Comment: @KurtRevis — No, I certainly don't want to. :) Which is why I am asking if anyone knows if anyone has done this already. It would be nice to have wrappers for CGPath as well. UIImage seems like a decent wrapper for CGImage; I've begun using that for storing my CGImage instances. And I can't even count how many places I use UIColor instead of CGColor. Ideally, I would like to get rid of *all* manual retain and release calls in my code. I really dig ARC and I really dislike the manual retain/release calls. I've had zero memory leaks with managed objects, but several with manual CG pointers.

Comment: UIBezierPath wraps CGPath already.

Comment: This got me thinking about how one might improve the CGBitmapContext API (particularly `CGBitmapContextCreate`), more substantively than just redeclaring it in Objective-C syntax. I wrote it up: http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2012-06-01/on-the-api-design-of-cgbitmapcontextcreate Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: State management aside, I'd like this merely to remove the redundant eye-stabby "CGContext" prefixes littering an otherwise straightforward drawing recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) class, according to the docs, "is an Objective-C wrapper for the path-related features in the Core Graphics framework... [it] is really just a wrapper for a CGPathRef data type and the drawing attributes associated with that path."  The ["Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html) has a description of this class with some nice diagrams. (See also its cousins [NSBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [CGPathRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGPathRef).)

As for a wrapper for CGContext itself... *Update*: ...after I wrote my own proof-of-concept wrapper, I discovered [MPWDrawingContext](https://github.com/mpw/MPWDrawingContext) by Marcel Weiher. It adds a bunch of useful methods, and supports chaining too!

---

I just whipped up a [Ruby script](https://github.com/alexch/unsuck/blob/master/cgcanvas.rb) to generate a wrapper class for CGContext called CGCanvas:

- https://github.com/alexch/unsuck/blob/master/unsuck/CGCanvas.h
- https://github.com/alexch/unsuck/blob/master/unsuck/CGCanvas.m
- [usage docs](https://github.com/alexch/unsuck#cgcanvas-a-wrapper-for-cgcontext-methods)

It's not very useful yet, but it proves the concept. I like being able to see the parameter names, though the API is still cumbersomely functional.

Before:

```
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(30.0, 210.0, 60.0, 60.0));
CGContextAddArc(context, 150.0, 60.0, 30.0, 0.0, M_PI/2.0, false);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, 150.0, 60.0, 30.0, 3.0*M_PI/2.0, M_PI, true);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

After:

```
[canvas fillEllipseInRect:CGRectMake(30.0, 210.0, 60.0, 60.0)];
[canvas addArc_x:150.0 y:60.0 radius:30.0 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI/2.0 clockwise:false];
[canvas strokePath];
[canvas addArc_x:150.0 y:60.0 radius:30.0 startAngle:3.0*M_PI/2.0 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:true];
[canvas strokePath];
```

I did some tricks to make the names make sense... for instance, function names with more than one parameter get the name of the first parameter appended to the base name (unless it already ends with it). I used an underscore instead of the more Cocoa-like "with" to separate the base name from the parameter name, e.g. `moveToPoint_x:y:` instead of `moveToPointWithX:y:` or `moveToPoint:y:`.

If I continue using this class, I'll probably add more constructors, and maybe some block methods ([like this guy did](http://www.natestedman.com/post/improving-cgcontext-with-blocks/)), so you can start, build, and stroke a path all at once. Also a lot of names could be shorter still, and a lot of methods could use some defaults.

And maybe method chaining! If only Objective-C wasn't so bracket-crazy. It would have to look like this:

```
[[[[[[[[canvas
  setRGBStrokeColor_red: 1.0 green: 1.0 blue: 1.0 alpha: 1.0]
  setRGBFillColor_red:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]
  setLineWidth:2.0]
  fillEllipseInRect:CGRectMake(30.0, 210.0, 60.0, 60.0)]
  addArc_x:150.0 y:60.0 radius:30.0 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI/2.0 clockwise:false]
  strokePath]
  addArc_x:150.0 y:60.0 radius:30.0 startAngle:3.0*M_PI/2.0 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:true]
  strokePath];
```

(which isn't *so* horrible, I suppose...)

Comment: What is the benefit of this over [UI|NS]BezierContext and such?

Comment: I think you mean `UIBezierPath`/`NSBezierPath` and let's see... according to the docs, "The UIBezierPath class is an Objective-C wrapper for the path-related features in the Core Graphics framework," so yeah, it seems pretty useful! In theory there is more to the CGContext than just stroking and filling paths but it remains to be seen how more more life can be squeezed out of a separate OO wrapper. I did this mainly as a tutorial exercise for myself and I'm happy to learn more about `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: ...and, after I wrote my own proof-of-concept wrapper, I discovered [MPWDrawingContext](MPWDrawingContext) by Marcel Weiher.

It adds a bunch of useful methods, and supports chaining too!